# If $2^{\sqrt {200}}=a^a$ is known, determine the value of $a^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, exponential-function

Let $a$ be a real number. If $2^{\sqrt {200}}=a^a$ is known, determine the value of $a^2$.

My approach uses the Lambert ${W}$ function.

$\sqrt {200}\log {2}=a\log {a}$
$10\sqrt {2}\log {2}=a\log {a}$
$\log {a}\times e^{\log {a}}=10\sqrt {2}\log {2}$
$\log {a}=W(10\sqrt {2}\log {2})$
$a=\exp W\big(10\sqrt {2}\log {2}\big)$.

Hence, my answer is $a^2=[\exp W\big(10\sqrt {2}\log 2\big)]^2$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Try simplifying your answer.

Comment: Hi :) There has to be an easier solution. Observe $\sqrt{200}=\sqrt{100}\cdot\sqrt 2=10\sqrt 2$. Further $2=(\sqrt{2})^2$. We get $2^{\sqrt{200}}=\sqrt{2}^{2\cdot 10\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}^{20\sqrt 2}=\sqrt{2}^{5\cdot 4\sqrt{2}}$ Now calculate $\sqrt 2^5$

Comment: since you've added the tag contest math, there must be a more beautiful solution, that is easier to compute and only requires elegant manipulation and  a little bit of "_seeing through_".  See @Jochen 's comment

Comment: With properties of the Lambert W-function it can be determined that $W(10 \, \sqrt{2} \, \ln(2)) = \frac{5}{2} \, \ln(2)$. This gives $\text{exp}(W(10 \, \sqrt{2} \, \ln(2))) = (\sqrt{2})^5 = 4 \, \sqrt{2}$ as stated in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified further though to $a^2=32$. [And to get anything close to full credit, I imagine you must observe this, especially if this is indeed a contest queztion.]

HINT: Note:

$$2^{\sqrt{200}} = 2^{5 \times 2\sqrt{2}} = (32)^{2\sqrt{2}}$$
$$ (\sqrt{32})^{4 \sqrt{2}}.$$